# charset cp852 and ISO 8859-2

Tags: java, character-encoding

Is it possible that while loading characters from `.dbf` file with charset `cp852` to

```
ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
```

and save that to xml file with encoding `ISO 8859-2` can occur data loss?

In internet explorer and java collections all charset seems to be ok, but when I add data from xml to database I lose my letters like `ą`, `Ą` , `ś`, `Ś`

Comment: Could you post your code how do you read the XML and store the data in the database? Maybe you try to store the data as UTF8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, it is pretty much possible as displayed on this code (though it will be fine if you only want to export simple letter).

```
public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // try to print Upper case A with ogonek
        System.out.println(new String(new byte[] {(byte) 164}, Charset.forName("IBM852"))); // <--- will print the correct character
        System.out.println(new String(new byte[] {(byte) 164}, Charset.forName("ISO-8859-2"))); // <--- will print something else
    }
}
```

the result in my place will look like this

> Ą 
>   ¤

for further reference, you could check these two links

http://www.ascii-codes.com/cp852.html 
http://www.calculla.com/en/iso8859_2_table?action=showAll

Comment: Now, how can I change cp852 to ISO?

Comment: well, you can convert it yourself (cp852 -> utf-8 -> iso 8859 2 or vice versa) or change the database encoding.