# How to fix encoding problem with Czech chars, while using BluetoothManager for printing?

Tags: android, encoding, printing, android-bluetooth

I've got the old project in Java and for sure I met there with some small problem.

here is the code:

```
public boolean printerPrint(List<String> list) {
    if (btMan != null) {
        try {
            // Select character code table (ESC t n) - n = 16(0x10)
            btMan.getOutputStream().write(0x1B);
            btMan.getOutputStream().write(0x74);
            btMan.getOutputStream().write(0x10);

            for (String s : list) {
                byte[] byteLine = (s).getBytes(ISO_8859_1);
                String line = Util.byte2HexStr(byteLine) + " 0A";
                btMan.SendData(line);
            }
            btMan.SendData("0A 0A 0A");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Timber.e(e, "printing stop failed");
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here is the screenshot from the app, this bill should be the same after print.

[image]

Here is the bill after print:

[image]

Some of the letters are not printed (š, ě, č, ř, ž), but they have been replaced by "?".
I tried to use ISO8859-2(the same problem as in ISO-8859-1, but instead of replacement by "?", they have been replaced by some letters which aren't correct), UTF8/UTF-8(especially with this it doesn't work at all).

### If someone ever met with that, any advice is good.

Comment: Your codes are fine...Just check your thermal printer support for Unicode encoding or [Czech codepage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_852)

Comment: @ecle Thank you very much for your answering, but this printer which I use is for 100% support Czech Language (text&grafic). But no printing them this is very strange...

Comment: I just notice, please use "UTF-8" or "ISO_8859_2" instead of "ISO_8859_1" since Czech is 8859 Latin 2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29532029/charset-cp852-and-iso-8859-2

Comment: @ecle Thank you for your advice about "UTF-8" or "ISO_8859_2" instead of "ISO_8859_1". First of all, I tried to use "UTF-8", but it doesn't work in general, it was look like that: "Uzávěrka" without "UTF-8" and with "Uzä väìrka", but with "ISO_8859_2" it looks a little bit better "Uzávìrka", but still it wasn't the correct word "Uzávěrka". Thanks for your advices tried everything but still no fix my problem:(